# git is unable to access .idea on windows 10

Tags: windows, git

Windows has some problems with the name of files/folders like .idea which starts with dot. I've created my project and I want to use git, however when softwares like tortoise git or Source tree try to check my files I get error like this:

```
warning: unable to access '.idea':Permission denied fatal: cannot use .idea as an exclude file.
```

So they can't check files and folders. Also I created a directory and put an empty .idea folder in it, and it still shows the same error. I run Source Tree as administrator user.

I've  recently upgraded my OS to win 10. Previously in win 7 I did not have such problems.

So what should I do for this special folder?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to C:\Users:username\.gitconfig
and delete line excludesfile = .idea